# Meteor/Cordova Background Color how to convert colors?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

So I'm using Meteor / Cordova for an app on mobile. In my mobile-config.js I have this line :

```
App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0xff0000ff');
```

Which basically sets the app background to white.

I want to set it with this color : #41c569

I kept searching but couldn't find how to convert this hexa color into a 4 bytes.

Comment: IIRC the only difference is that the last two characters are opacity. I think using `App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0x41c569ff')` is what you want

Comment: Thank you ! But unfortunately It doesn't work, I wonder if the problem is the color or meteor which doesn't read mobile-config...

Comment: I think it's the other way around. Opacity is the first 2 digits instead of the last 2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html